# How to set a dynamic Expires header in Jetty?

Tags: jetty, url-rewriting, servlet-filters, expires-header, jetty-8

Jetty allows headers to be set using the jetty-rewrite functionality, but it doesn't appear to be very smart, and only accepts a fixed string.

How do I tell Jetty to send an "expires in 8 hours" header?

With Apache .htaccess and mod_expires you can do ["access plus 8 hours"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) but of course Jetty doesn't understand .htaccess files, nor can I find any info on a similar construct in jetty-rewrite.xml

```
<Call name="addRule">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.HeaderPatternRule">
            <Set name="pattern">*.png</Set>
            <Set name="name">Expires</Set>
            <Set name="value">access plus 8 hours</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

That just sends the literal text "access plus 1 day" back, which is of course ignored by the client.

Could/should this be done with a servlet filter? Jetty has a [Gzip filter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/GZIP_Compression) but doesn't appear to offer something similar for dynamically setting headers.

Answer (score 1):

That could be a nice feature..

Open an enhancement for it at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty.  Patches are welcome, either attached to the bug or pushed into our gerrit instance.

That being said...the jetty xml is really an xml layer over java so I suspect you could actually so this in java if you can find the APi for it.  I think there is a joda time library that has a method where you could wire up something that would call new DateTime().plusHours(8) to populate that value.

Probably better to add it as a feature though.

Comment: What I'd _really_ like is the ability to process these rules directly in a .htaccess file (so I can use familiar and concise syntax), but I'm guessing there'd be little point in opening an enhancement request for adding htaccess support?

Comment: go for it, it would be nice if we had a resource handler that grokked the format...I can't say we'll get to it anytime soon but if its there someone might step up and implement it and contribute :)